# how to move focus to an item in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have implemented a list with infinite scroll in my demo application.on click of any row it will go to `detail screen`. It is working fine.

**I am facing  a issue to focus the last selected row  ** In other words

1. Run the application .it load first `20` items.Scroll to bottom to load more 20 items.
2. Then click any item let say `33`rd row . it will display `33` in detail page.
3. Now click on `back` button it show focus on `0` or first row. I want to move focus to `33` row .or Move the scroll position to `33` position.

I use `useContext` api  to store the `items`(all rows/data till last scroll) and `selected item` (selected index).

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-cdn-2osdg?file=/src/useInfinitescroll.js

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useListState } from "./context";
function Detail({ location, history }) {
  const state = useListState();
  console.log(state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          history.replace({
            pathname: "/"
          });
        }}
      >
        back
      </button>
      <h2>{location.state.key}</h2>
      <h1>detaiils</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Detail);


 any update?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a single source of truth for your element position. As an example I put the state of the position on the Router component since this seems to be the parent of the App component & Details.

```
const Router = () => {

  const [previousClickedItemPos, setPreviousClickedItemPos] = useState(0);
  
  /* import useLocation so that useEffect can be invoked on-route-change */
  const location = useLocation();

  /* basically pass this to the list items so you can update position on-click */
  function handleClickList(element) {
    setPreviousClickedItemPos(element);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    /* scroll to the element previously selected */
    window.scrollTo(0, previousClickedItemPos);
  }, [previousClickedItemPos, location]);

  ...
```

---

On your InfiniteList component:

```
<ListItem
    onClick={e => {
        dispatch({
            type: "set",
            payload: items
        });
        handleClickList(e.target.offsetTop); /* update position state */
        goDetailScreen(item);
    }}
    key={item.key}
>
    {item.value}
</ListItem>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-breeze-nwtln?file=/src/router.js

Answer (score 1):

Use this before you redirect to the detailed page and store it in a state.

```
let position = document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

This will give your current position on the page. Once you are back to list view use

```
window.scrollTo(0, position)
```

to go back to where you were initially.